# How can I create dynamic routes/ screens with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, routes, native

I want to create dynamic routes similar to the way you can with react-router using the slash colon as so:

```
<Route exact path="/user/:_id" component={UserPage} />
```

How does this work with react native if I want to open a page specif to a link?

```
const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Button
      onPress={() => {
        alert(`You tapped ${title}`);
      }}
      title={title}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </Button>
  </View>
);

const MainPage = () => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);


export default MainPage;
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MainPage" component={MainPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MediaScreen" component={MediaScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want the Item onPress to go to its own page/screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for as I know react native navigation doesnt allow url params, you have to pass parameters when you call the navigate function.

```
const Item = ({ title, navigation }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Button
      onPress={() => {
        alert(`You tapped ${title}`);
        navigation.navigate('Details', { _id })
      }}
      title={title}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </Button>
  </View>
);

const MainPage = ({ navigation }) => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} navigation={navigation}/>}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);


export default MainPage;
```

Then in Details it will have a route parameter which you can get _id from `route.params._id`

```
const Details = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const [_id] = useState(route.params._id);
    return (
        <></>
    )
};
```

Comment: I am getting "undefined is not an object (evaluating navigation.navigate)"

Comment: How are you getting to MainPage from HomeScreen? From what I can see right now when your app boots it should start at HomeScreen and then you would need to navigate to MainPage somehow, curious how you're doing that

Answer (score 1):

With react-navigation you can pass parameters in two ways:

1 - Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter to the navigation.navigate function: `navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })`

2 - Read the params in your screen component: `route.params.`

Full documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params